# C++ Create a vector of objects with variables passed into constructor

Tags: c++

The program I'm writing uses a 2D array of a map to create objects, written for the GBA. Because the map will be changed for each level, I won't necessarily know how many objects of each type there will be so I decided that a vector would be my best bet for this, however I've run into some problems. This is the relevant code:

main.cpp

```
void CreateObjects(const uint8_t map[32][32]){        // line 91
    std::vector<wall> WallsVector;
    for(int y = 0; y < 32; y++){
        for(int x = 0; x < 32; x++){
            switch(map[y][x]){
                case 0:     // do nothing
                    break;
                case 1:     // wall
                    WallsVector.push_back(wall((x*8), (y*8)));
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

wall.h

```
#ifndef __WALL_H_INCLUDED__        // line 3
#define __WALL_H_INCLUDED__

#include "library.h"
#include "gameBlock.h"
#pragma once

class wall:public gameBlock {
public:
    wall(int, int);
    ~wall();

private:

};

#endif
```

wall.cpp

```
#include "wall.h"                    // line 3

wall::wall(int passX, int passY){
}

wall::~wall(){
}
```

This gives me these errors:

```
main.cpp:99: undefined reference to 'wall::wall(int, int)'
main.cpp:99: undefined reference to 'wall:~wall()'
```

Along with several other similar ones, relating to the destructor and `'_Destroy<wall>'`.

It also ends with the error:

`collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status` (which is the bane of my life).

If anyone can give any insight into what's going wrong it'd be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: It turns out I was being silly and forgot to add the wall.o to the makefile.

Comment: It sounds like you didn't actually compile and link `wall.cpp`

Comment: You're exactly right, I forgot to add `wall.o` to the makefile. I feel so daft. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the feedback I got. My problem was solved by Matt McNabb, I had forgotten to link the file by adding `wall.o` to the makefile.

Answer (score -2):

I think there is problem in `WallsVector.push_back(wall((x*8), (y*8)));`,

you may need to enter new object like ,
`WallsVector.push_back(new wall((x*8), (y*8)));`,

Comment: no, I don't think so. It's a compiler/linker error. That should not be related to wall being allocated on the stack or with new.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to add wall.o to the makefile. It's compiling fine now.

Comment: The use of `new` would require the vector to hold pointers to `wall`, not `wall`s.